# Use of "emeritus" adjective

Tags: adjectives, adjective-phrases

Can I use "emeritus" adjective colloquially (i.e., not necessarily in academia settings)?

Comment: Please show us some research when posting questions. Thanks.

Comment: [*Mr. Mix is a veteran , but far from being **a manager emeritus**. He is training up a son, who already ably assists him...*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22mr+mix+is+a+veteran+but+far+from%22) That's from *The Insurance Times* (1893), so obviously the usage has been around a *long* time. Many other examples will have the term in "scare quotes", though, to alert the reader that the writer is "playing fast and loose" with language.

Comment: When are you planning on using it, and of whom, and with what precise meaning? It's often going to sound humorous or jocular, for instance if you call your kid a bedwetter emeritus, meaning he's stopped pissing himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not normally.  The established use is "Emeritus Professor". Other uses are jocular or "marked" (for example marked as making a point that a retired person has high level of respect similar to that of a retired professor)

It might be used successfully by a native speaker to make this point, but it would probably be considered "just a mistake" if an English learner did the same.

Comment: Thank you. That’s exactly what I needed. Yes, I did plan to use it humorously